# Simple D3 code for drawing area charts

Tags: javascript, beginner, data-visualization, d3.js

I am quite new to D3 and JavaScript in general, so I'm sure there is a way to write the following in a lot less code:

```
function CalculatePeriodReturns(){
    periodReturns = [];
    [...]
    periodReturns.push({
        length: [...],
        mean: [...],
        pctile50: [pctile(0.25),pctile(0.75)],
        pctile90: [pctile(0.05),pctile(0.95)],
        pctile99: [pctile(0.005),pctile(0.995)],
        min: [...],
        max: [...]
    });
}

function DrawChart(){
    var margin = {top: 20, right: 100, bottom: 30, left: 100},
        width = $("#multiperiod_chart").width() - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = $("#multiperiod_chart").height() - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var svg = d3.select("#multiperiod_chart").append("svg")
        .datum(periodReturns)
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .attr("id", "multiperiod_chart_svg")
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform",
              "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var x = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width]);
    var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

    x.domain(d3.extent(periodReturns, d=>d.length));
    y.domain([d3.min(periodReturns, d => d.min), 
        d3.max(periodReturns, d => d.max)]); 

    var area99 = d3.area()
        .x(d=>x(d.length))
        .y0(d=>y(d.pctile99[0]))      
        .y1(d=>y(d.pctile99[1]))    

    svg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "area")
        .attr("id", "area99")
        .attr("fill", "#565A68")
        .attr("d", area99);

    var area90 = d3.area()
        .x(d=>x(d.length))
        .y0(d=>y(d.pctile90[0]))      
        .y1(d=>y(d.pctile90[1]))    

    svg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "area")
        .attr("id", "area90")
        .attr("fill", "#7B7F8B")
        .attr("d", area90);

    var area50 = d3.area()
        .x(d=>x(d.length))
        .y0(d=>y(d.pctile50[0]))      
        .y1(d=>y(d.pctile50[1]))    

    svg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "area")
        .attr("id", "area50")
        .attr("fill", "#A1A3AA")
        .attr("d", area50);

    [...]

}
```

For a start, is there a way to create an accessor `area(y0,y1)` that takes the two `d.pctileXX` properties as attributes or similar? Maybe I can combine the three `svg.append`'s as well?

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify your area generators, as well as your code to append the paths, using an `each` to append the paths or an object to define the `x` and `y` methods in the area generator.

However, there is an simpler alternative: you are facing all those difficulties because of the structure of your data. If you change your data's structure for a more adequate one you can create a code which is way more idiomatic, therefore easier to read and, the most important, easier to maintain.

Right now, this is your data structure:

```
var periodReturns = [{
    pectile99: [x, y],
    pectile90: [x, y],
    pectile50: [x, y]
}, {
    pectile99: [x, y],
    pectile90: [x, y],
    pectile50: [x, y]
}, {
    etc...
}];
```

You will bend over backwards to create a multiarea chart with a data structure like this, because:

1. The `data()` methods accepts a data array in which **each object** is a datum;
2. You cannot easily get the objects' keys;

So, let's change that data structure. We'll created a *nested* data, with a key/value pair for the name, conveniently called `name`, and a key/value pair (containing an array) for the points, conveniently called `values`:

```js
var data = [{
  pectile99: [0, 10],
  pectile90: [0, 40],
  pectile50: [0, 100]
}, {
  pectile99: [100, 40],
  pectile90: [100, 140],
  pectile50: [100, 30]
}, {
  pectile99: [200, 110],
  pectile90: [200, 10],
  pectile50: [200, 100]
}, {
  pectile99: [250, 90],
  pectile90: [250, 70],
  pectile50: [250, 140]
}, {
  pectile99: [300, 10],
  pectile90: [300, 30],
  pectile50: [300, 150]
}];

var nestedData = Object.keys(data[0]).map(function(d) {
  var obj = {
    name: d,
    values: []
  };
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    obj.values.push(data[i][d])
  };
  return obj;
});

console.log(nestedData)
```

Now, since all the points can be accessed using the same property name, we can easily write **just one** area generator. Also, since each object in `nestedData` corresponds to just one area, we can write a single enter selection!

```
var areaGenerator = d3.area()
    .x(function(d) {
        return d[0]
    })
    .y1(function(d) {
        return d[1]
    })
    .y0(150);

var areas = svg.selectAll(null)
    .data(nestedData)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
        return color(i)
    })
    .attr("opacity", 0.5)
    .attr("d", function(d) {
        return areaGenerator(d.values);
    })
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var data = [{
  pectile99: [0, 10],
  pectile90: [0, 40],
  pectile50: [0, 100]
}, {
  pectile99: [100, 40],
  pectile90: [100, 140],
  pectile50: [100, 30]
}, {
  pectile99: [200, 110],
  pectile90: [200, 10],
  pectile50: [200, 100]
}, {
  pectile99: [250, 90],
  pectile90: [250, 70],
  pectile50: [250, 140]
}, {
  pectile99: [300, 10],
  pectile90: [300, 30],
  pectile50: [300, 150]
}];

var svg = d3.select("svg");

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10)

var prop;

var nestedData = Object.keys(data[0]).map(function(d) {
  var obj = {
    name: d,
    values: []
  };
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    obj.values.push(data[i][d])
  };
  return obj;
});

var areaGenerator = d3.area()
  .x(function(d) {
    return d[0]
  })
  .y1(function(d) {
    return d[1]
  })
  .y0(150);

var areas = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(nestedData)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
    return color(i)
  })
  .attr("opacity", 0.5)
  .attr("d", function(d) {
    return areaGenerator(d.values);
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That doesn't quite solve it though - mind we need more than just the value pair to create an area chart, we also need "length": 
 `.x(d=>x(d.length)).y0(d=>y(d.pctile99[0])).y1(d=>y(d.pctile99[1]))`

We're more than free to change how the data gets populated in the first place by the way - my periodReturns.push({}) approach was just my own way of doing this without putting a lot of thought into this, and frankly I don't know any better!

Comment: @Oli The principle remains, just push any value you want inside the inner arrays.